# How to define a static dictionary and access it in Java?

Tags: java, android

How to define a static dictionary and access it in Java.
I do it like this in iOS Swift:

```
let pairs = [
     "Name1": "Value1", 
     "Name2": "Value2"
]

print(pairs["Name1"]) // Value1
```

How to do something like this in Java?

Comment: I think you are asking to define this static dictionary as a Name Value Pair in a file and not by implementing as a Map? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can use the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, and choose that implementation that best fits your needs; like:

```
Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
pairs.put("key1", "value1");
System.out.println("The value would be:" + pairs.get("key1");
```

You would also want to read about java [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) in general; and look into the corresponding [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). When you need a Map that can't be "changed" upon adding the initial elements; you would first populate an ordinary Map object; and then use [Collections.unmodifiableMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) afterwards.

Given your comments: Java's "built-in" java.lang.Map is always about a keys/value pairs. If you need more than one value, you would be using something like `Map<String, List<String>>` for example. Or you can turn to 3rd party libraries, such as Guavas [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like a good idea. Another question: Can I do something like Map<String,String,String> with map interface? I might need to hold more than 1 value for 1 key.

Comment: @TheCook no, you would need a different datatype for your value, e.g you could use a list like `Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();` or if it's a fixed number of values, an array or custom datatype

Comment: @mbdavis Your code example is wrong. You still say `new HashMap<>` ... the ArrayList comes into play when **putting** things into the map. You can't create the list when creating the map; sorry, but your code is total bogus.

Comment: This answer does not define a static dictionary. Should not be the accepted answer. @Héctor has the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41060064/2614353

Answer (score 11):

You could initialize the map inside `static` block, too.

```
public class YourClass {

  public static final Map<String, String> staticMap = new HashMap<>();

  static {
      staticMap.put("key1", "value1");
      staticMap.put("key2", "value2");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Guavas ImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) for a constant dictionary.

```
private static final Map<String, String> PAIRS = ImmutableMap.of("Name1", "Value1","Name2", "Value2");
```

If you have lots of entries you can use the

```
ImmutableMap.builder()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### A - Explanation

First you have to determine the functionalities of the dictionary you want in an interface. Then you can use simply a `HashMap` or a `Map` Implementation in your dictionary implementation. You can store the `(word, meaning)` pairs in your `HashMap`.

I've provided both a dictionary interface and an implementation with using the `HashMap` collection. The demo code and output is as below;

If you want to make the dictionary persistent, then you have to write the contents of the map to a text file.

#### B - Dictionary Interface

```
package com.levent.dictionary;

public interface Dictionary {

    void addToDictionary(String word, String meaning);
    void removeWord(String word);
    int count();
    boolean isExist(String word);
    String getMeaning(String word);

}
```

#### C - Dictionary Implementation with HashMap

```
package com.levent.dictionary;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DictionaryImpl implements Dictionary {

    private int count;
    private Map<String, String> wordMap;

    public DictionaryImpl() {
        count = 0;
        wordMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addToDictionary(String word, String meaning) {
        if(!isExist(word)) {
            wordMap.put(word, meaning);
            count++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeWord(String word) {
        if(isExist(word)) {
            wordMap.remove(word);
            count--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int count() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExist(String word) {
        if(wordMap.get(word) != null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMeaning(String word) {
        String meaning = null;

        if(isExist(word)) {
            meaning = wordMap.get(word);
        }

        return meaning;
    }

}
```

#### D - Dictionary Demo Code

```
package com.levent.dictionary;

public class DictionaryDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dictionary dict = new DictionaryImpl();

        // add word 'gitmek'
        String word = "gitmek";
        boolean isExist = dict.isExist(word);
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + " is exist in dictionary? : " + isExist );
        System.out.println("dict count: " + dict.count());

        dict.addToDictionary(word, "to go");
        System.out.println("\t" + "\"" + word + "\"" + " added to dictionary");

        isExist = dict.isExist(word);
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + " is exist in dictionary? : " + isExist );
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + ": " + dict.getMeaning(word));
        System.out.println("dict count: " + dict.count());

        System.out.println("\n*************************\n");

        // add word 'gelmek'
        word = "gelmek";
        isExist = dict.isExist(word);
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + " is exist in dictionary? : " + isExist );
        System.out.println("dict count: " + dict.count());

        dict.addToDictionary(word, "to come");
        System.out.println("\t" + "\"" + word + "\"" + " added to dictionary");

        isExist = dict.isExist(word);
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + " is exist in dictionary? : " + isExist );
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + ": " + dict.getMeaning(word));
        System.out.println("dict count: " + dict.count());

        System.out.println("\n*************************\n");

        // remove word 'gitmek'
        word = "gitmek";
        dict.removeWord(word);
        System.out.println("\t" + "\"" + word + "\"" + " removed from dictionary");

        isExist = dict.isExist(word);
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\"" + " is exist in dictionary? : " + isExist );
        System.out.println("dict count: " + dict.count());
    }

}
```

#### E - Demo Output

```
"gitmek" is exist in dictionary? : false
dict count: 0
    "gitmek" added to dictionary
"gitmek" is exist in dictionary? : true
"gitmek": to go
dict count: 1

*************************

"gelmek" is exist in dictionary? : false
dict count: 1
    "gelmek" added to dictionary
"gelmek" is exist in dictionary? : true
"gelmek": to come
dict count: 2

*************************

    "gitmek" removed from dictionary
"gitmek" is exist in dictionary? : false
dict count: 1
```